# What would be the direct translation of "aunque" in this sentence

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, gramática

[El escorpión de Corteza de Arizona vive en los desiertos porque sus capas de grasa lo mantienen hidratado **aunque** se esconde debajo de cobijos como rocas o hojarasca en pleno día.](http://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Wikichicos/Ar%C3%A1cnidos/Escorpi%C3%B3n)

Is the direct translation of `aunque` here "while" or "even while"?

Why was `aunque` chosen instead of another preposition, such as `y`? It seems to clash with the "The scorpion lives in deserts" phrase. Is it common in Spanish to have sentences with this type of grammar?

In other words, what would be the best English translation for this sentence?

I would think it would be one where "aunque" is translated to "even while" but I don't find any listings of aunque meaning "even while," though it can mean "while." The only way for it to keep the meaning of "aunque" as "although" in English would be have "although it hides under rocks" separated by a comma or in parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, but I think there is a problem of word choice. I would remove the "aunque" and put a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Although* is fine, that's the most direct and correct [translation](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=although); a comma would have been nice in the original sentence too, for it would have made the meaning clearer.